# Find 13th min value in table group by a column

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to replicate Small function in Excel which is Small(Array,K) gives Kth smallest element from stream of data.

I want to find 13th Min value for perticular Column values. in my table I have 2 columns A and B for each A column row value I have lets say 20 B values. I am trying to find 13th Smallest value for Each A value from column B

I am using following query to get min from group by clause

```
select A,min(B) from test group by Level_Name
```

I want to find 13th smallest value and not the smallest value.

I added tried a new query as

```
with a as(
select A,B,ROW_NUMBER() over (order by A,B) as rownum 
 from test 
group by Level_Name,pl
)
select A,B from a 
where rownum=13
group by A,B
```

It is returning only 13th number for 1 of the A value but there are multiple rows in A.

Comment: [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql).

Comment: Can there be duplicate values in column `B` for a given column `A`?

Comment: Right now no duplicates.

Comment: @V_immo - and, for each group `A`, are there _at least_ 13 rows?

Comment: @ScottHodgin Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick solution would be to use [Row_Number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and select for the row number you are interested in.  Something like:

```
--demo setup
Declare @Table table (ColA int, ColB int);
insert into @Table(ColA,ColB) values
(1,10),
(1,20),
(1,30),
(1,40),
(1,50),
(1,60),
(1,70),
(1,80),
(1,90),
(1,100),
(1,110),
(1,120),
(1,130),
(1,140),
(1,150),
(1,160),
(1,170),
(1,180),
(1,190),
(1,200),

(2,10),
(2,20),
(2,30),
(2,40),
(2,50),
(2,60),
(2,70),
(2,80),
(2,90),
(2,100),
(2,110),
(2,120),
(2,130),
(2,140),
(2,150),
(2,160),
(2,170),
(2,180),
(2,190),
(2,200);

--solution
select * from 
(
select *,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by ColA order by ColB) as rn
from @Table
) a
where rn = 13;  --The row number you are interested in.
```

---

```
| ColA | ColB | rn |
|------|------|----|
| 1    | 130  | 13 |
| 2    | 130  | 13 |
```